# getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Driver must be set error on running feature file in BDD cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

**This is my Runner class:**

```
``package baseclass.local.Ios;


import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import uitests.ios.Page.DirectoryWidget;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static server.local.AppiumServerTest.startAppiumServer;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources",
        glue = "src/test/java/uitests/ios/Page",
        tags = "@tagname",
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"
        }
)
public class LikesTest {

    public AppiumDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
        startAppiumServer();
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        caps.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 14 Pro");
        caps.setCapability("n", "4CE8F504-2285-47D9-AA52-371550EB3873");
        caps.setCapability("wdaStartupRetries", "4");
        caps.setCapability("iosInstallPause","8000" );
        caps.setCapability("wdaStartupRetryInterval", "20000");
        caps.setCapability("appium:noReset", "true");

        caps.setCapability("app", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sandmann-bxvuahotesmmbjhbcbaqtalefoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Polario.app");
        this.driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        System.out.println(this.driver);
    }
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void LikesTest() throws MalformedURLException {}`
```

**This is feature file:**

```
Feature: Likes

  #1 when there is a like button then user should be able to like the page or news
  @Positive
  Scenario: Like Page or News
   Given the user has login to the app and navigated to Page or News
    When user press on like button
    Then user has liked the page or news
```

**This is step defination class:**

```
`package uitests.ios.Page;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;

public class Likes {
    public AppiumDriver driver;
    AppiumDriver thatDriver;
    public Likes(AppiumDriver driver) {

        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }
   @Given("the user has login to the app and navigated to Page or News")
    public void the_user_has_login_to_the_app_and_navigated_to_page_or_news() {
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(40));
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        try {
            if (allowNotificationsBtnOnSystemDialogue.isDisplayed()) {
                allowNotificationsBtnOnSystemDialogue.click();
                new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(2));
                allowNotificationsBtnOnSystemDialogue.click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(email));
                email.click();
                email.sendKeys("test@api.plazz");
                password.click();
                password.sendKeys("T123plazz");
            }

        }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            email.sendKeys("test@api.plazz");
            new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            password.sendKeys("T123plazz");

        }
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        loginBtn.click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));

        try {
            if (allowNotificationsBtnOnSystemDialogue.isDisplayed()) {
                allowNotificationsBtnOnSystemDialogue.click();
            }

        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {}

        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> condition = ExpectedConditions.or(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(userTitleOnHomePage_Android),
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(userTitleOnHomePage_iOS)
        );

        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        //scrollDown();
        smallScrollDown();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        //opening project
        projectForAutomationOnHomePage.click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(projectMenuBtn));


        if (projectMenuBtn.isDisplayed()) {
            projectMenuBtn.click();
            System.out.println("1st clicked");
        }
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        actions.moveToElement(pageMenuItem).click().build().perform();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(6));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(titleOnPageTop));

        System.out.println(  "test is run successfully");

    }
    @When("user press on like button")
    public void user_press_on_like_button() {

        likeBtn.click();
    }



    @Then("user has liked the page or news")
    public void user_has_liked_the_page_or_news() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(40));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(likedToastMessage));
    }



}`
```

**not sure why i am getting this error. if i call the step definition methods from runner class and just run the step runner class then i don't get any error but if i run the tests from 'feature' file as a scenario then i am getting the error.**

**not sure why i am getting this error. if i call the step definition methods from runner class and just run the step runner class then i don't get any error but if i run the tests from 'feature' file as a scenario then i am getting the error.**

**I want to run the scenario from feature file, i am expecting that 'setup' method in runner class will launch the app and then it will run the step definitions.**